# How Can I execute a shortcode wordpress in a iframe

Tags: iframe, wordpress

i use a plugin wordpress [rating Widget](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rating-widget/) and i have a liste that i add with iframe and i want to add this rating to this liste the plugin use this code for php shortcode but when i add in to the iframe it dosnt work some but it wrk in other page of wordpress some one can help me please

[php rw_the_post_rating($postID , $class='page'); ?]

Comment: my understanding is you'll need to include wp-load.php in your iframe source file for the shortcode to be processed. I may be wrong.  You might find it easier to use the function WP uses directly.

Comment: it dosnt work i add  include_once('../../../../wp-config.php' ); but still same things

Comment: wp-load not wp-config, you'll need to make the page appear as if it apart of WordPress. if that's the case you could just create a template page with the code in and use `get template part` function to include it on your page. why does it need to be an iframe?